# Screen after Bootanimation

Tags: cyanogenmod, custom-roms

[image]What is the name of screen that shows after bootanimation ,splash screen ?
Android is upgrading box. How do i change logo like custom roms (ex; tesla rom) where do i find them ?

Comment: There's nothing after **boot animation** - you're already in the normal system UI. Splash screen is _before_ boot animation and is _not_ in ROMs (and worse, usually _not_ alterable). "Android is upgrading" is a part of system UI. What are you looking for?

Comment: yeah thanks for the clarification. I have added picture above.And i have decompiled framework-res.apk , systemUI.apk but couldn't spot the files.

Comment: Oh that one. Decompile /system/priv-app/SystemUI.apk (might be on a slightly different path) or /system/framework/framework-res.apk to look for the image resources.